# How to build till a particular changeset number TFS API 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-sdk

Suppose I have a list of changesets 1 to 10. Is it possible to specify that it build till changeset no. 5, instead of building just for a particular changeset or all the changesets 1-10?

I know It's possible to specify a particular version of the files to build, like changesetId,Date,Label,latest and workspace versions. So how do I specify "Build till C5" when triggering a custom build in my application?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that using the default build process template. In the "Advanced" section of the build process parameters (in the Process tab of the build definition editor), set the "Get Version" parameter to the changeset you want to build (e.g. "C5"). More logically, you would do this in the Queue Build dialog's "Parameters" tab.